# Changing date on ESRI Basemap, to display different basemap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-online-basemaps

I am trying to create a map using the ESRI Basemap on ArcGIS 10.3. 
The Problem I am having is that the area I want to map is covered by cloud, making details impossible to see. Is there a way to change the date on the ESRI Basemap, to a previous date so that I can eliminate the cloud cover?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out-of-the-box in ArcGIS, but there is a commercial option called Nearmap which allows this - see https://go.nearmap.com/esri

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do that you would need that particular basemap service to support historical imagery, and for your client to be able to control the dates of imagery provided.  You could ask for this in an ArcGIS Idea.

To see an example of an imagery service that does for a local geographic area you could look at [Aerial Comparison through Time - Historic Imagery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=37d83a2f080642ca8ae02f60443b60ba) whch is a:

> Map showing Cottonwood Heights over time using aerial imagery

Answer (score -1):

If you have any problem in base map image, you should clip that part of image from Google map or from quick bird satellite image. Then replace it your own problem area using georeferencing  tool.

Comment: For the moment, that is what I have done. I was wondering if the ESRI Basemap had the functionality to display back-dated images, which would be useful to know in the future :) 
Thankyou!

Comment: I think you should check for any Google Maps and QuickBird licensing issues before considering this solution.